# A simple OOP code run in DEV-C++ compiler but not in VS 2019, WHY?

Tags: c++, compiler-construction

I am angry, I get these compiler errors a lot. Here is the code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

class Creature
{
public:
    Creature();
    string getName(string name);
private:
    string Name;
    float Health;
};
string Creature::getName(string name)
{
    Name = name;
    cout << Name << endl;
}
int main()
{
    Creature Igor;
    Igor.getName("Adun");
    return 0;
}

Creature::Creature()
{
    cout << "A creature has been created" << endl;
}
```

Tell me  why is that difference happening between compilers. I tried to run this code in the website called C++ SHELL it run perfectly fine.

Comment: Your function `Creature::getName` says it returns a string, but it doesn't have any `return` statement. Right now, the function is a bit confusing, it's hard to tell if it's supposed to be a getter or a setter. It's named `getName` and is declared to return a `string`, but it takes `string` as an argument, performs a set, and then doesn't return anything in the implementation. Figure out what the function is actually supposed to do and make its declaration match that.

Comment: Can you tell me why some compilers are fine with it and some are not? @Nathan Pierson

Comment: Some compilers are fairly lax about enforcing C++ standards. In this case, the MSVC compiler is strict (and correct).

Comment: Thank you. So these being fairly lax about a code can create bad results if we ignore what it supposed to be always, then. okay. I mean then some compilers are not good to learn coding. They are simply leading bad coding... @Nathan Pierson

Comment: Yeah. Even C++ Shell produces a warning letting you know about the missing `return` statement, which you ignored. VS automatically promotes that warning to an error unless you specifically instruct it to leave it as a warning and permit compilation anyway.

Comment: yeah I saw that now @Nathan Pierson

Answer (score 1):

`Creature::getName` function has been declared to return non-void. However, then function neither returns a value nor throws an exception. As a result, the behaviour of the program is undefined.